# Trying to display data in table from an array in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have some code in Angular 6 to display data, but the code I have tried to implement does not work? My code so far:

**TS file**

```
  incident = [ 
    {id: 'E200', product: 'MP2355 Black and white', floor: '2', address: '11 Rue', code: '75019'},
  ];

  incidents = this.incident[0];
```

**HTML file**

```
<tr class="" *ngFor="let state of incidents">
    <td>{{state.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `id` doesn't appear to be a property on your `incidents` object.

Comment: `incidents = this.incident[0];` I don't get this, or the rest of the example. There is no `id` key in your sample data. Please update your question.

Comment: Sorry typo, the id was the serial number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
incidents = this.incident[0];
```

You are taking only one object from array so it can't iterate the loop in view.

```
this.incidents=this.incident;
<tr *ngFor= "let incident of incidents">
<td>{{ incident.id }} </td>
..
..
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should not that be just incident instead of incidents?

```
<tr class="" *ngFor="let state of incident">
    <td>{{state.id}}</td>
</tr>
```